# php error and lumen error both showing on error output

Tags: php, exception, lumen-5.2

How can I fix this issue in **lumen framework**?

I am getting the PHP default errors and lumen framework exception both at the same time.

Here I have attached the screenshot of both files. The output and the exception handler PHP file.

[image: Output of the exception or error]

[image: lumen exception/handle.php file]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.  Text should be cut-paste here.  Ok for the display, but code?  Nope :-)

Comment: fixed grammar and improved formatting

Comment: @Nic3500 I have added screenshot because it is the default file for the exception rendering and reporting in the lumen framework the only reason I have put the screenshot over here is that people who know lumen can know that I have not done any changes in this file.

Comment: Seems that php config should be adjusted, check Your `display_errors` directive

Comment: @PeterM i already set it to true but in laravel these issue is not occurring so is there any way that in lumen we can set it.

Comment: @PeterM or i have to set it manually in the bootstarp/app.php.?

Comment: You can set it to `false` with `ini_set`.

Comment: @PeterM is it the only way?

Comment: If framework does not set it maybe. Or just set it in `php.ini`, on production it should be false anyway.

Comment: May we see the file...`ParticipantController.php`...`line 4788`...

Comment: I removed the semicolon manually on line 4788 to get the error message there is nothing over there. @ChukwuemekaInya

Comment: So, the problem is that you only want `lumen` error to show on the output and not `php` and `lumen` huh?.

Comment: In .env file, set `APP_DEBUG` to `false` and check.

Comment: yah something like that @ChukwuemekaInya

Comment: @Jigar ... Setting `APP_DEBUG` to `false` will turn that of Lumen off.

Comment: How can I fix this issue? Which issue? The issue you implanted manually by removing semicolon on line 4788 of ParticipantController.php or what issue? The question does not clarify anything.

Comment: @bigyanshr sorry for not clarifying the whole thing in the question. but I think from the screenshot you can see that I am getting the error output with both exceptions with PHP exception and with the lumen exception So I just want to turn off the PHP exception.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit Maybe it's lumen version issue, Please upgrade your lumen version otherwise disable display_errors.

Comment: sure let me try this one @Pramodkushwaha

Comment: Unable to understand why i'm getting - (minus) for this question. It's a valid question that both should not displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Oh... You need to try any of the following:

**Method 1**

Assuming you are running `apache` web server and `php 7.2` on an `Ubuntu` PC.
Go to your `php.ini` file (`/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`), search for `display_errors` and set it to `Off`.

If **Method 1** doesn't fix it for you, try **Methods 2**:

**Method 2**

Go to the `index.php` inside the `public` folder of your `app` and turn off `display_errors` like so:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);   //Set this before $app->run();
```

Comment: So it's a bug in lumen 5.2 that it not automatically stop displaying php errors like laravel 5.2 right? @Chukwuemeka Inya

Answer (score 0):

To display the comprehensive error, I added the following configurations.

**config/app.php**

```
return [
    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', true),
    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),    
];
```

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Comment: I already know this one. Just wondering and posted this question because the php error display should be disable by default in the lumen framework it self so we cannot see both the errors as which is already in laravel framework